# Enable swipe in TabView

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using NativeScript Angular and have a TabView that is set to the bottom position. I would like to allow the user to swipe between tabs on both iOS and Android but in the [TabView docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/tab-view) it says that swiping has been disabled when the position is set to bottom.

How do I enable swiping on the TabView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading about the gesture API I ended up doing it by adding a swipe event listener to the TabView:

HTML:

```
<TabView #tabview (swipe)="onSwipe($event)" androidTabsPosition="bottom">

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Start', iconSource: getIconSource('play')}"
        name="startTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Settings', iconSource: getIconSource('settings')}"
        name="settingsTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

</TabView>
```

TypeScript:

```
@ViewChild("tabview") tabview!: ElementRef<TabView>;
...
  onSwipe(event: SwipeGestureEventData) {
    if (this.tabview.nativeElement.selectedIndex === 0 && event.direction === SwipeDirection.left){
      this.tabview.nativeElement.selectedIndex = 1;
    } else if(this.tabview.nativeElement.selectedIndex === 1 && event.direction === SwipeDirection.right){
      this.tabview.nativeElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: I presume this wouldn't have the 'slide' animation when you're swiping it, right?